# c++ : inherit std::array and store reference to inner values

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, c++14

Let's suppose I would like to define a struct which can be seen as a 2D array, but which also provide member like accessors to the content of the array.

For example, one could write a `Point2D` struct that would essentialy be an array, but also provide x and y *members* (not accessors). Such a struct could serve as a bridge between different libraries : I work with some libraries that consider a point as having x a y members and some others which see it as being an array.

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4H-gae

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>

struct Point2D : public std::array<double, 2>
{
    using Base = std::array<double, 2>;
    Point2D(Base && v) : 
        Base(v),
        x(operator[](0)),
        y(operator[](1))
    {}

    double &x, &y;
};

void test() 
{
    Point2D p({1., 2.});
    assert(p.x == 2.);
    p.x += 4.;
    assert(p.x == 5.);
}
```

Is such a use case reasonable or am I asking to be shoot in the foot repeatedly by various UBs?

If such an approach is reasonable, is there a way to make the constructor constexpr?

Comment: No, such a struct most definitely cannot serve as a bridge between libraries, unless one of the libraries for some ungodly reason uses `Point` with two *reference* members.

Comment: @n.m : agreed for the type conversion. However; it can work for generic programming : `template<typename PointType> double Norm(PointType && pt)` would work for example.

Comment: A generic library that doesn't provide its own point type but requires that the user-provided one has members named `x` and `y`? I'll pass.

Comment: "A struct that can be seen as a 2D array". This is a peculiar requirement. Where is this requirement coming from? Otherwise you could have used composition and provided the x, y as references to member std::array.

Comment: Aren't you just asking for a union, or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617101/zero-cost-properties-with-data-member-syntax) is one possible approach to the problem.

Comment: A major issue is that if a Point2D  is copied then the references will point to the old copy. It seems that your client code is not wedded to a particular implementation of Point2D. Could you have inline methods X() and Y() that return temporary references into the std::array?

Comment: @GemTaylor : You are right, this is a no-go ! I think I'd better opt for methods, although this will require some adjustment on the client code side. My original idea was 
 to create a strong type (https://foonathan.net/doc/type_safe/) on top of an existing implementation from another library.